# MEF Composition Import Issue

Tags: mef

I have a MEF composition question. In my development environment I am able to use this code to import parts.

```
var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path, "MyCompany.*.dll");            
var container = new CompositionContainer(dirCatalog);
container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
```

However when I deploy to a test server that doesn't work. The only way I have found to make it work right is to explicitly load the the dlls that have exports like this:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, "MyCompany.Services.AppServer.Modelling.dll"))));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, "MyCompany.IFS.AppServer.Dispatchers.dll"))));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, "MyCompany.Services.AppServer.Service.dll"))));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, "MyCompany.IFS.Common.InstrumentService.Proxy.dll"))));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, "MyCompany.IFS.Common.InstrumentPropertyService.Proxy.dll"))));

var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
```

Obviously, I don't really want to explicitly load every dll that has an export in it; that sort of defeats the purpose of MEF. But, right now that's the only thing I have found that works.

This code is in a custom service host factory used for starting a WCF service hosted in IIS. Not sure that that matters...

TIA,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the **DLL file names** inside an **XML** or other **config file**.  At least you won't have to recompile.

I'd suggest having at least..

**Filename** and **IsEnabled**, that way you can just toggle IsEnabled instead of having to comment in the XML file.

Comment: Putting the DLL file names in a config file will still defeat the purpose of MEF.

Comment: A config file provides far more flexibility than explicitly stating each DLL in code. MEF provides extensibility. Just because you have to state which parts to include, does not defeat the purpose of providing extensibility. (It only involves one more step.)